# How do you develop a plugin for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, toolbar

I have tried with the help of many sites which is available in the Google search.
However, I didn't get any solution for IE.

I want to build a plugin-in from scratch. I have the experience in Firefox plugin development but not in IE.

Answer (score 11):

There's an open source project called [FireBreath](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath) which allows you to write a plugin for IE and NPAPI (Firefox, etc.) from a single codebase. It's [a year old](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/09/a-year-in-the-life-of-an-open-source-project/) now, so it's becoming pretty mature.

Be sure you're looking to develop a plugin though, not an extension. Here's a [rundown](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/) of the differences.

Comment: I am not sure if you are aware of it, but this is like the only good reference to materials that can be found out there for .net developers. I sure will read your blog :)

Comment: If you're referring to the colonelpanic.net links, that's not mine. That's the blog of the guy who did Firebreath. I so have a blog of my own though, linked in my profile. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to write a [plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) and not a browser [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_extension):
The term for internet explorer plugins is - misleadingly - [content extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741312%28VS.85%29.aspx#content_extensions). Specifically they are implemented as [ActiveX controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). MSDN also features an article specifically about [ActiveX controls for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751970.aspx).
If you go that road, note that [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9adwcde.aspx) eases most of the aspects of COM/ActiveX implementation.

If you want to have cross-browser support though, i'd personally go with [Schnapples suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298566/ie-plugin-development-help/3728822#3728822) of using FireBreath as it gives you an abstraction layer over the major differences.

Comment: Wikipedia now redirects `browser extension` to `plugin` so your links are not all that useful anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a great site for IE Addons http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

and this one
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/09/06/461675.aspx