# Create IE Addons

Tags: internet-explorer-8, add-on, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking for a tutorial to make addons for IE 8 or 9.  Can you provide me with a resource.
Please, for the sake of peace and everything else, I already know I can make FF or Chrome addons. I *want* to make an IE addon.
Thanks.

Comment: <snarky_comment type="IE_addon" reason="obligatory" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you develop a plugin for IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298566/how-do-you-develop-a-plugin-for-ie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [this site](http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp)?

Comment: Additionally, you might check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298566/ie-plugin-development-help  Looks like they reference the same site and additionally point to a blog.