# Budding C# developer... I want to write an IE9 addon... how?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create IE Addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730034/create-ie-addons)

I don't know where to start, but given that I haven't done programming in years (VB6 was the last I did), I am trying to start out again and learn C# properly. That said, I am giving myself a project to start first, and I figure if I can work on that first it would be ideal because I'm pursuing a goal in software, as well as learning something.

How do I go about starting to make an IE9 addon?

Thanks!