# (Java) Is it possible to read Internet Explorer form data?

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I'm just getting started with this process, but figured I'd ask if it is possible with only Java.

At work, we use an intranet for much of our work.  I am developing an application that uses some of the information from those websites.  However, we currently need to copy from IE and paste into my JavaFX application.

I was wondering if Java provides any sort of integration with the Windows API that would allow me to automatically pull that data from IE to my app.

For example, there is a web-based form with several textfields; I want to be able to capture the text that is written in them, programatically.

**EDIT**: I do not have access to the website code directly.

Comment: If you are just copying the data into your app anyway why not just replace the existing web form with a java app embedded into the page? Then you avoid the whole problem of capturing data entered into a web page

Comment: That's beyond the scope of what I'm developing.  I basically just need a couple of small bits of information from a larger, very complex web form.

Comment: You could parse the web page if you really wanted to but you'd be much better off consuming a web service if there is one or you could just straight up do get / post requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm i dont think it work that way,

you can make a java **scraper** , who is a program to get the code html of a certain page, but you cant get data from a form, because the clients are diferents.

maybe you can send from web client form the user/password to an app, but you cant make an intrusion from app to a form who is in a web page with content in the value of form fields

Comment: Do happen to know what language would be capable of doing so?  I know it is possible to do so because my work already has an application that does it (it is old and outdated; I am creating a replacement for it).  But since the old app's developers are not here, we do not have a way to update it or examine its source code.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get form data from IE but you can't put code into the website. It sounds like a task for a **plugin**. Consider [developing your own plugin or extension (probably in javascript) in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298566/how-do-you-develop-a-plugin-for-ie).